# Nginx Reverse Proxy To Remote Nginx Server Running PHP Application

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have setup a PHP application running on a RHEL server with the following configuration and also made a few changes in the nginx.conf file, the application is running fine.

**magento.conf**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server   unix:/run/php-fpm/magento.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/magento-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/magento-error.log;
    include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

I have another nginx server that i am trying to use as a reverse proxy to the PHP application running on the remote server. The issue i am facing is when i load the site from my Nginx IP, the URL in browser changes to the IP of PHP application server.

I want the IP to remain same as of the Nginx server instead of changing to IP of PHP Application server

The configuration file for reverse proxy is below
**reverse.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  #server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass http://10.128.0.10:80;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: My suspicion is that one or more redirects lead you away from your nginx (redirects are sent to the client's browser and it executes them). Have you installed nginx-extras? Then I could show you with a Lua script that intercepts redirects. Stay healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Without Lua you can try to edit your `proxy_redirect off;` line to `proxy_redirect http://10.128.0.10:80 http://my.domain.com:80;`.

Maybe repeat that line with a slash at the end and/or https at the beginning (port 443 instead of 80).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291007/239596

Comment: I made the changes and added the line, but still it keeps redirecting to the Application Server IP, i do not have a domain so i am using Public IP
      proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
      proxy_redirect  http://10.128.0.12:80 http://NginxPublicIP:80;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Comment: Try to eliminate the redirects (which the backend delivers). You can check with `curl -IL <URL>` (have a look for 301, 302, 303.. redirects). Or tell me when you have Lua.

Comment: @ qräbnö : Yes I can see a 302 redirect through CURL, i tried the redirect directives and all but still not able to find the solution. I can see that the nginx-extra are paid and not free. Is there any script or any language i need to install for this redirection issue.

Comment: nginx-extras is free. You mean the chargeable Nginx Plus. If you install nginx-extras with apt or something like that, you have to make a backup of /etc/nginx first, enter sudo apt purge nginx and then install nginx-extras (e.g. on Debian or Ubuntu). Write me if you have it, then I will post you a Lua reply.

Comment: I have installed some extra nginx modules such as nginx-headers on the RHEL servers and also installed lua language. Can you please provide the script and also if I may ask any other solutions you might have in mind.

Comment: I have found the issue, when in the proxy pass i set the public IP of the remote server the URL remains the same, if i keep the private IP the url changes in the browser. i am running a php site on the remote server on top of php-fpm. Is it something to do with it?

Comment: This means for me that the PHP backend gets or reads or uses the IP from proxy_pass and makes the redirect based on it. This is not a new insight for me. I offered my solutions, if someone else has others, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

With Lua:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    # server_name example.com;

    # resolver 127.0.0.11:53;  # Docker-DNS. Needed for proxy_pass with variables inside!

    set $MY_SCHEME http;
    set $MY_HOST example.com;
    set $target "${MY_SCHEME}://${MY_HOST}";

    location /
    {
        rewrite_by_lua_block
        {
            local map = {
                GET = ngx.HTTP_GET,
                POST = ngx.HTTP_POST,
            }
            ngx.req.read_body()
            local res = ngx.location.capture('/example123' .. ngx.var.request_uri, {
                method = map[ngx.var.request_method],
                body = ngx.var.request_body
            })
            -- Detect/change redirect...
            local redirect_target = res.header.Location
            if redirect_target and res.status > 300 and res.status < 309 then
                -- ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, 'redirect_target: '..redirect_target)
                local redirect_target_changed, n, err = ngx.re.gsub(redirect_target, '^https?[:][/][/]10[.]128[.]0[.]10', ngx.var.target)
                -- ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, 'redirect_target_changed: '..redirect_target_changed)
                return ngx.redirect(redirect_target_changed, 303)
            elseif res.status == 500 then
                return ngx.exit(500)
            else
                ngx.exec('@example123_normal')
                return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
            end
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/example123(.*)$
    {
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://10.128.0.10:80$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect http://10.128.0.10/ $target/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location @example123_normal
    {
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://10.128.0.10:80$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect http://10.128.0.10/ $target/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Totally untested. And if you can't do Lua and RegEx, it gets hard.